# Remove custom xml namespaces with xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to remove namespaces in an xml document and getting the following error:

ERROR:  'The prefix "car" for element "car:name" is not bound.'
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The prefix "car" for element "car:name" is not bound.'

Here's my xml file:

```
<car:name>Toyota Corolla</car:name>
<car:year>2000</car:year>
```

Here's my removeNs.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="vLowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="vUppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element
            name="{concat(translate(substring(local-name(), 1, 1),                              
                              $vUppercase, $vLowercase),
                    substring(local-name(), 2))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my java method:

```
    private static String stripNameSpaces(String inXml) {
        String outputXml = "";
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("./src/main/resources/removeNs.xslt"));
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
            Source text = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inXml));

            transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(writer));
            outputXml = writer.toString();

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tcEx) {
            tcEx.printStackTrace();
            return tcEx.getMessage();
        } catch (TransformerException tEx) {
            tEx.printStackTrace();
            return tEx.getMessage();
        }
        return outputXml;
    }
```

My guess is that I have to add something to removeNs.xslt but have not been able to figure out what. If someone could help me with this, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: That snippet you have shown is not a namespace well-formed XML document, it doesn't have any common root element and it doesn't declare a namespace for the prefix `car` used in the element names. So you won't be able to run it through any XML parser, it doesn't even get to be processed by XSLT, it is simply the XML parser rejecting the input.

Comment: Note that if the XML was well-formed, and with a namespace declaration, the XSLT works fine (assuming you did also want to convert the first letter to each element name to lower-case)

Comment: can you give me an example of a well-formed xml?

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpY for an example of your XSLT in action for well-formed XML. Where does your XML come from, anyway? If someone else is producing it, you should really ask them to send you well-formed XML.